# Get Data from Firestore async

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from my Firestore database but i cannot manage to do this properly.

My Problem is that console.log(allData.length) always prints 0 because i guess it overtakes the async part of the code but i cannot figure out to make "userDataSnapshot.docs.map" somehow async aswell. Any tips on how I can do this properly?

```
      const allData = [];
      const userDataSnapshot = await db.collection("userdata").get();
      userDataSnapshot.docs.map(async (doc) => {
        var userObject = [];
        userObject.push(doc.id);
        var snapshot = await doc.ref.collection("advanceddata").get();
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          userObject.push(doc.data());
        });
        allData.push(userObject);
      });
      console.log(allData.length);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will help:

```
  const allData = [];
  const userDataSnapshot = await db.collection("userdata").get();
  for(const doc of userDataSnapshot.docs) {
   var userObject = [];
    userObject.push(doc.id);
    var snapshot = await doc.ref.collection("advanceddata").get();
    snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      userObject.push(doc.data());
    });
    allData.push(userObject);
  }
  console.log(allData.length);
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I did not know that this for loops work that nicely. It takes quite some time to go through a mid sized data set but it works! Thank you!